# #menubutton is behaving oddly. It's flickering.

Tags: html, css

The  #menubutton with the red background fails to work properly once I scroll down the page. If I do not scroll it appears to work fine. How do I fix this issue?

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
#banner
{
width: 100%;
height: 328px;
background: url(img/banner_background.jpg) repeat center fixed; 
position: relative;
padding-top: 25px;
overflow: hidden;

}
.flex-container 
{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
#menubutton
{
position: fixed;
top: 80px;
right: 20px;
background-color: red; 
height:68px;
width:68px;
display: block;
z-index: 3;
}
#menubutton:hover
{
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
right: 20px;
background: url(img/menuup.jpg) no-repeat center ; 
height:68px;
width:68px;
display: block;
}
#biglogo
{
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 0.7s;
}
@keyframes example {
    0%   {margin-top: 200px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0px;}
}
#work
{
width: 100%;
height: 94px;
background-color: #3de1ff;
padding-top: 10px;
}
#work a
{
margin-left: 100px;
}
#logoscrolls
{
width: 100%;
}
/* The Overlay (background) */
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */    
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 10; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
}

/* Position the content inside the overlay */
.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%; /* 25% from the top */
    width: 100%; /* 100% width */
    text-align: center; /* Centered text/links */
    margin-top: 30px; /* 30px top margin to avoid conflict with the close button on smaller screens */
}

/* The navigation links inside the overlay */
.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block; /* Display block instead of inline */
    transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position the close button (top right corner) */
.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

/* When the height of the screen is less than 450 pixels, change the font-size of the links and position the close button again, so they don't overlap */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
#first
{
min-height: 527px;
background: url(img/gbackgroundtest.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
font:25px/30px 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}

#second
{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
}
#second2
{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;

}
.row {
width: 100vw;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fluid-container
{
background: red;
}
.remove-padding 
{
padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0
} 
.underline
{
text-decoration: underline;
}
#firstoverlay
{
position: absolute; /* Sit on top of the page content */
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #3de1ff;
opacity: 0.5;
cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
z-index: 3;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: bluefade;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
display: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
#firstoverlayv2
{
position: absolute; /* Sit on top of the page content */
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #3de1ff;
opacity: 0.5;
cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
z-index: 3;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: bluefade;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
display: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes bluefade {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: .5;}
}

#firstoverlay22
{
position: absolute; /* Sit on top of the page content */
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #3de1ff;
opacity: 0.5;
cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
z-index: 3;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: bluefade;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
display: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#firstoverlay2
{
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index:3;
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: btw;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-play-state: paused;
color: white;
}
#firstoverlay2v2
{
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index:3;
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: btw;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-play-state: paused;
color: white;
}
#firstoverlay2two
{
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index:3;
width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: btw;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-play-state: paused;
color: white;
}
@keyframes btw {
    0%   {color: white;}
    100% {color: green;}
}

#line
{
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: linegrow;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
display: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#line2
{
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-name: linegrow;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
display: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes linegrow {
    0%   {width: 0px;}
    100% {width: 200px;height: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;}
}
#firstoverlay2:hover > #line
{
display: block;
}
#firstoverlay2v2:hover > #line2
{
display: block;
}
.spacebelow 
{
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.wlink, .wlink:hover
{
color: white;
font-style: italic;
text-decoration: none;
}
body
{
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* fixes anti-alias issue */
}
#listservice
{
list-style: none;
margin-top: 10%;
}
#listservice2
{
list-style: none;
width: 250px;
padding-top: 2%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#listservice li
{
margin-bottom: 10px
}
.listfix
{
margin-right: 5px;
}
#First2
{
height: 270px; 
width: 100%;
background: url(img/gbackgroundtest.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
font:25px/30px 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
z-index: 0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  
  <!-- START Google Analytics -->
  
  <!-- END Google Analytics -->  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli|Nanum+Gothic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<section class="flex-container" id="banner">
<a href="#" id="biglogo"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png" alt="Digital Marketing - 2Teso" height="282px" width="282px"></a>
<a href="#" id="menubutton" onclick="openNav()"></a>
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

</div>
</section>
<section id="work">
 <marquee id="logoscrolls" behavior="scroll" direction="left">
<a href="#" id="spalogo"><img src="img/spalogo.png" alt="Shangrila Massage Spa" height="72px" width="116px"></a>
<a href="#" id="minilogo"><img src="img/minilogo.png" alt="2Teso Mini Logo" height="72px" width="73px"></a>
  </marquee>

</section>

<div class="fluid-container d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block">
<div class="row remove-padding">

<div id="first" class="col" onmouseover="on();" onmouseout="off();">
 
 
 <div id="firstoverlay" >
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="firstoverlay2" >
 <span  id="textfade" class="spacebelow">Your Business. Online.</span>
 <div id="line"></div>
 <a class="wlink" href="#">View Our Services</a>
 </div>
 
 
  

</div> <!-- First End-->


<div id="second" class="col">

<ul id="listservice">
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/seoicon.jpg" alt="seoicon">SEO</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/webdevicon.jpg" alt="web development" >Web Development</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/ppcicon.jpg" alt="ppc icon" >PPC</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/gdicon.jpg" alt="graphic design" >Graphic Design</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/movieicon.jpg" alt="video & cartoon" >Video & Cartoon</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/cwicon.jpg" alt="copy writing">Copy Writing</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/smicon.jpg" alt="social media">Social Media</li>
</ul>

</div> <!-- Second end -->


</div> <!-- row end -->
</div> <!-- fluid container end -->

<div id="First2" onmouseover="on();" onmouseout="off();" 
class="d-block d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none">

 <div id="firstoverlayv2" >
 </div>
 
 
  <div id="firstoverlay2v2" >
 <span  class="spacebelow">Your Business. Online.</span>
 <div id="line2"></div>
 <a class="wlink" href="#">View Our Services</a>
 </div>

</div> <!-- Second First END -->

<div id="second2" class="d-block d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none" >

<ul id="listservice2">
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/seoicon.jpg" alt="seoicon">SEO</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/webdevicon.jpg" alt="web development" >Web Development</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/ppcicon.jpg" alt="ppc icon" >PPC</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/gdicon.jpg" alt="graphic design" >Graphic Design</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/movieicon.jpg" alt="video & cartoon" >Video & Cartoon</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/cwicon.jpg" alt="copy writing">Copy Writing</li>
<li><img class="listfix" src="img/smicon.jpg" alt="social media">Social Media</li>
</ul>

</div> <!-- Second2 end -->




<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}

function on() {
    document.getElementById("firstoverlay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("firstoverlayv2").style.display = "block";
    
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("firstoverlay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("firstoverlayv2").style.display = "none";
}



</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Could it be the marquee? The fixed position? It also works fine if I use position absolute, but I need to use fixed as I want the menu to be available anywhere on the page.

Comment: I don’t see any flickering in the snippet provided here. Please verify that you see the problem with that here as well, and tell us in which browser(s) you see it happen.

Comment: I don't see any flickering either

Comment: It happens on safari 11.1.2, and yes it happens on here also.

Comment: try moving the scroll bar down and you will see once you past the marquee the button becomes very hard to click, and does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my CSS. The `#menubutton:hover` was set to absolute, and the `#menubutton` was set to fixed. This caused the button to jump to another position when I hovered.